# I cannot upload image into amazon server in ios8?

Tags: ios, xcode, image, amazon-web-services

I want to upload my image into amazon server but its not uploaded. I refer many posts and found the one object "AmazonS3Client". I use the cocoa-pods and add the framework like pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2' but I can't get 
"AmazonS3Client" object into my project.  please help me for uploading the image.

my cocoa-pods podfile :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'AWSiOSSDKv2'
pod 'MBCalendarKit', '~> 2.2'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 3.7'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AmazonS3Client` is from the version 1 of the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS, which has been deprecated. You should use `AWSS3TrasnferManager` or `AWSS3` in the version 2 of the SDK instead. You can take a look at [AWS Mobile SDK Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/) and the S3TransferManager Sample at our [GitHub repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples) for further details.

Comment: Thanks,Yosuke Matsuda.